# Java Disruptor Handling Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, disruptor-pattern

In the disruptor (version 3.3.2), each event is a Runnable (since EventProcessor extends runnable).

I am writing an application that whenever an EventHandler throws an exception, the class who calls disruptor.start() needs to catch the exception and then react.

Now, if an EventProcessor would have been a Callable, that would have been easy.

Is there another way in Disruptor to propagate the exception?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by passing an implementation interface to the EventHandler, 
as suggested by the Doug Lea book. The exception is set in a LinkedList, and at the end of the method call I retrieve the last element in the list. Sample code:

```
    final LinkedList<Throwable> listExceptions = new LinkedList<Throwable>();

    MyClassWithDisruptor at = MyClassWithDisruptor.getInstance();
    at.send(message, transport, conf, new AuditExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleException(final Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        @Override
        public void setException(final Exception e) throws AuditTrailException {
            listExceptions.add(e);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The disruptor provides an [ExceptionHandler](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/ExceptionHandler.java) which intended for dealing with this sort of problem.